# Installing Ubuntu Desktop on HP MicroServer Gen10

Tags: system-installation

I am wanting to install Ubuntu Desktop on a new HP Microserver Gen10.

I have built a bootable USB and added the install media to it, it boots and gives me the choice to try Ubuntu or install, either way I then get the Ubuntu splash screen with the scrolling dots followed by a blank Ubuntu desk, nothing more happens.
[image: Screenshot]

I have tried it with RAID setup and with no RAID configured.

Any thoughts on what the problem may be?

Thanks All.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install the GUI and display manager on the machine (via terminal or SSH). If you're looking for a default experience:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

For mate:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-mate-desktop
```

For kde:

```
sudo apt install kdefull kubuntu
```

For cinnamon

```
sudo apt install cinnamon
```

The standard choice for a server GUI is XFCE, because it is very lightweight. To get it:

```
sudo apt install xfce4 lightdm
```

To minimize what any of these pull in, use the --no-recommends be option. If you wish to access your GUI remotely, you will need to install xrdp and tell it to use your GUI. To do that, you simply type the command to start you specific GUI (**not startx, but the command for the GUI, like XFCE is startxfce4**) into each users ~/.xsession file

To get your dock, you will need a tool called gnome-tweaks

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the info. Just to be clear the image I have displayed is pre install. do your instructions still stand? Thanks.

Comment: @Mr_M_Cox my advice is to actually inthe GUI **on** the server, as the USB stick will install over your OS, change it from Ubuntu server to Ubuntu desktop. The USB media is intended to _install_ Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I was able to bypass this by changing some boot options. I was using Ubuntu MATE but it should be the same for regular Ubuntu:

- Pressed shift during boot to get into the boot menu.
- Pressed F6 for "other options"
- Added combination of "acpi=off", "acpi=off", "nomodeset" to grub options.
- Booting with those options loaded to the desktop, and I was able to install.

Not exactly sure what the reason is for the problems.
[pic of boot screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNsNE.jpg)